# Link triggering XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have made a simple XMLHttpRequest which does work, it sends request etc. Just like in W3 schools.

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demox").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", "textx.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("fname=" + textxx);
}
```

The problem starts when I try to trigger the request by clicking a link, which sends me to the php file which processes the request. I find it hard to understand on my current level why it doesn't work, since it worked with simple forms and such.

I get:

```
"Notice: Undefined index: fname ..."
```

So, I assume, it means the variable wasn't sent. Can someone explain? Or is there way to debug the things that are being sent from one page to another. All I found was a debugger in chrome which indeed captures the requests, but has no real use, since I get sent to the textx.php page and all is lost.

Comment: It does work if I trigger JS code via <button>, but when I use <a href> it does work but, it seems, the progress on the loaded page is lost.  `<button type="button" onclick="loadDocx()">Test x</button> <a href="textx.php" onclick="loadDocx()">Test x2</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, where your problem might be, maybe try:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.open("POST", "textx.php", true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4){
        if(this.status===200 || this.status===0){
            document.getElementById("demox").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    var fname = "fname=" + textxx;
    xhttp.send(fname);
}
```

You might `console.log(xhttp);` and see the step by step profile and find out where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, I am still not sure, but I uploaded my page(code) to a hosting server and the code worked. PHP didn't show any warnings and all went as planned. The problem it seems has to do something with running a local server(WAMP). Changing PHP version didn't help. I may need to dig a little deeper on this.